# Image size issue, width and height not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, size

This is the style: `style="width:30px;height:30px;`
which I tried and other CSS to an image, but stays original size?

Comment: Share your HTML code and the image URL

Comment: <img src="url" width="30" height="30"> Try this @DerekPK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the image size is being overridden somewhere else. To counter this,

> style="width: 30px !important;height: 30px !important;"

The !important specifies that the property given should override any other class property or image property

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the code in body instead of style and see does it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that your CSS might be getting overridden with any other CSS, to deliberate your CSS you can use !important For ex

```
style="width: 30px !important;height: 30px !important;"
```

It would be better if you share your html and css code for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Directly use this in your img tag**

width="30" height="30"